# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ray.tune.suggest'

Tags: python, pytorch, ray

I have installed ray, and I am trying to import

`from ray.tune.suggest.hyperopt import HyperOptSearch`

but I keep receiving

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ray.tune.suggest'`

I checked the documentation but didn`t see anything that can give me a clue about this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Which documentation have you checked (add a link)? Which command have you used to install `ray.tune.suggest`? Which command have you used to run your Python program? Please add all details to your question.

Comment: @pts I was looking for Hyperparameter tuning with Ray Tune examples in PyTorch, and I liked this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBJd8BQWK8Q . I wanted to reproduce it, but I stuck to this ray.tune.suggest ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search gave me https://maxpumperla.com/learning_ray/ch_05_tune/ , which suggests adding this to the beginning of your notebook (and running it):

```bash
! pip install "ray[tune]==2.2.0"
! pip install "hyperopt==0.2.7"
! pip install "bayesian-optimization==1.3.1"
! pip install "tensorflow>=2.9.0"
```

You can try these lines or something similar. You may want to ask the author of https://youtube.com/watch?v=YBJd8BQWK8Q on what `! pip install` command they use.